# Property 'System.' is not defined for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer'

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I got this run-time exception

> Property 'System.String Name' is not defined for type
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer

When I'm trying to run a query.

My model relationship is as the image :

[image: models]

This is my model classes:

`Order` class

```
public class Order : BaseObject
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string OrderCode
    {
        get
        {
            return Constants.OrderCodePrefix + Id;
        }
    }
}
```

`OrderDetail`

```
public class OrderDetail : BaseObject
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }        

    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }

    public virtual TrackTrace TrackTrace { get; set; }
}
```

`TrackTrace`

```
public class TrackTrace
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TrackTraceId { get; set; }        

    public virtual List<TrackTraceStatus> TrackTraceStatus { get; set; }

    public Guid OrderDetailId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderDetailId")]
    public virtual OrderDetail OrderDetail { get; set; }
}
```

`TrackStatus`

```
public class TrackStatus
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TrackStatusId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<TrackTraceStatus> TrackTraceStatus { get; set; }
}
```

`TrackTraceStatus`

```
 public class TrackTraceStatus : BaseObject
{
    public int TrackTraceId { get; set; }

    public virtual TrackTrace TrackTrace { get; set; }

    public int TrackStatusId { get; set; }

    public virtual TrackStatus TrackStatus { get; set; }
}
```

I have cut off some unnecessary properties to make it simple.
This is my service class where I make the query:

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    AuthContext _dbContext;
    public OrderService(AuthContext context, ICommonDataService commonDataService)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
    }

    private IQueryable<Order> IncludeTrackingChildrent()
    {
        return _dbContext.Orders.AsNoTracking()            
        .Include(o => o.OrderDetails)
            .ThenInclude(o => o.TrackTrace)
                .ThenInclude(tr => tr.TrackTraceStatus)
                    .ThenInclude(ts => ts.TrackStatus)
        .Where(o => o.OrderDetails.Any(m => !m.IsDeleted))            
        .Where(_ => !_.IsDeleted);
    }

    public async Task<BaseSearchResponse<Order>> Search(string trackStatus)
    {
        var response = new BaseSearchResponse<Order>();

        var query = IncludeTrackingChildrent();

        //search by tracking status
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(trackStatus))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.OrderDetails.Any(d => d.TrackTrace.TrackTraceStatus.Last().TrackStatus.Name == trackStatus));
        }                    

        response.Items = query.Skip(0).Take(30).ToList();            

        response.Total = response.Items.Count();
        return response;
    }       
}
```

In my system, an `Order` is having multiple `OrderDetail`, each `OrderDetail` is have a `TrackTrace` table to tracking the delivery status, a `TrackTrace` is having from 1 to 5 `TrackStatus` like: Ordered, Delivering, ToOfficeA, ToOfficeB, ToCustomer.
The query purpose is: get the `Order` which is having any `OrderDetail` which is having the last `TrackTraceStatus` which have `TrackStatus` 's name is equal to the input string.

The problem is come out when I tried to get an element of the list `TrackTraceStatus`, I have tried `Last()` `LastOrDefault()` `First()` `FirstOrDefault()` or `ElementAt()`. All of these functions give me the error. I don't know to get the **Last** `TrackTraceStatus` to check its `Name`

Comment: Define "Last". There is no such term in database queries. Same as "First" btw. There must be involved some order.

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, can you give me a suggestion on how to get the Last item?

Comment: Sure I can try. But you need to tell me what "Last" means to you. i.e. some order criteria. Let me formulate it differently. When you have several `TrackStatus` records, which one is "last" - the one with **max** `TrackStatusId` or ??

Comment: "the one with max TrackStatusId" -> yes @IvanStoev

Answer (score 2):

Apart from EF Core translation/processing bugs (I'm getting a different exception with your query, but anyway), fundamentally you should avoid `Last` functions and use `First` / `FirstOrDefault` / `Take(1)` after applying ordering operator, because without explicit ordering operator, the order of the returned records is undefined, hence "first", "last" etc. make no any sense.

Based on comments, the goal is to find the last `TrackStatus` of `OrderDetail` (where last means the one with max `TrackStatusId`) and check if it's name matches a condition.

The first part can be achieved by "navigating" to the `TrackStatus` records and then using the typical for "last" `OrderByDescending` + `FirstOrDefault` pattern. For the second part, simply `Select` the name before calling `FirstOrDefault`, then compare the result to the desired name:

```
query = query.Where(o => o.OrderDetails.Any(d => d.TrackTrace.TrackTraceStatus
    .Select(tts => tts.TrackStatus)
    .OrderByDescending(ts => ts.TrackStatusId)
    .Select(ts => ts.Name)
    .FirstOrDefault() == trackStatus));
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, I have tried your code but it isn't work as expected. Thanks to your answer I have write my own stored procedure to solve problem instead of using linkq